# Is it possible to make a preview of my Ruby code in web browser with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby

I wrote some code for Tic Tac Toe game, which works fine in terminal. My question is, is it possible to make some kind of web app using that code and for example javascript (not using Rails)?

Comment: Hello @sawa, thanks for the reply. I am .NET developer and I am familiar with javascript, but I am not familiar with Ruby that much, I am a newbie in it. Any good suggestion, link will be gratefully accepted. I have my time.

Comment: close voted because the question is far too broad. Please keep in mind that SO is for narrow technical questions. There is a lot of solutions for what you are trying to achieve ; I'd suggest you take a look at lightweight frameworks like sinatra, or simply run a rack app, or even run a very simple HTTP server. You could also try to hang around in [the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) and ask for directions there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @m_x. I was aware of that fact, but I needed to ask.

Comment: Hi again @m_x, can you put you answer as a separated answer and I will flag it as correct. You can of course edit it a bit. I did it with "run a rack app".

Comment: sorry, would be a bit contradictory to answer a question I close-voted... ;) glad I could help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of solutions for what you are trying to achieve ; I'd suggest you take a look at lightweight frameworks like sinatra, or simply run a rack app, or even run a very simple HTTP server. You could also try to hang around in the chat and ask for directions there. –  m_x Jun 29 at 12:43

Answer (score 0):

Look at Opal: http://opalrb.org
you can basically translate the ruby code to javascript and run it in the browser (caveats apply)